# How do I shift the execution of a batch file from one CMD to another CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, powershell, cmd.exe

This is my batch file script:

```
::opens new cmd in admin mode
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs" 

::this needs to execute in the previously, newly opened cmd
wmic product where name="xxx" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

To use the `wmic` it requires an elevated administrator command prompt. I found the powershell command which actually opens the cmd in admin mode, however, when I try to run the following instruction, it selects the original command prompt which is not in admin mode...

Is there any way to continue the execution of my script in the **newly** opened cmd window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to store the command(s) you want to pass to `cmd` in a batch file, then call the batch file instead of `cmd`.

Eg, file.bat:

```
wmic product where name="xxx" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

Then call the script the same way you were attempting to,

```
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process file.bat -Verb RunAs"
```

Comment: is it possible to pass in parameters via the powershell.exe script? I.e. `installer.bat 2000 -u` and then: `powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process file.bat %arg1% %arg2% -Verb RunAs"`

Comment: Your comment is off topic to the original question. Yes, it is possible. You should do some more research on exchanging parameters between batch/Powershell and, if you have troubles, post a new question.

Comment: I'll do some further research and post new question if required. Thanks again!